# Expression for "a regular bencher" in sports?

Tags: expressions

How would one describe a player in a team that is not playing much, and is usually just on the bench for most of the games?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not much of a sports expert so I don't know if there's an official term, but I've always heard the phrase "bench-warmer" used to describe those types of players.

Comment: Thanks Thom. It seems there is even a Benchwarmers movie: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0437863/

Comment: Compare the term **super-sub**, which I've heard extensively in British football commentary to refer to someone on the bench who, rather than being weak, is actually being kept in reserve as a tactic, and is usually an excellent player.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [term is:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bench)

> bench: Sports . (of a player) not participating in play, either for part or all of a game.